# Returning results of operations from a message-loop in different thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some theoretical question regarding "message loops"; particularly returning result of operations happening in a message loop that runs in a different thread. I have the situation where I'm having a TCP server listening for incoming messages. For each incoming message the server will authenticate the client who sent the message and two things may happen:

1. If the authenticated client has an attached handler the received message will be passed to the handler's message queue.
2. If the client has no handler a new one will be created and the same as above (the message will be passed to its message queue).

The handler is currently an object implementing the Callable interface so that it'll run in a different thread and its simple enough the get the result of the operation. Now for my problem: Each handler can have N amount of messages to be processed. The handler has a "message loop" like functionality that runs until a timeout occurs - a timeout in this case would be the socket's idle time reaching a predefined treshold. What I would like to know, how can I get Java to return a value from within the message loop without actually terminating the thread. Something like the following:

```
while (true) {
    if (expired(socket))
        break; // the callable will finish the call() method.

    // get the first item from the queue.
    message = messageQueue.poll();

    result = process(message);

    // I want to return the result to the caller which is in a different thread.
}
```

Now obviously a return statement would stop the message loop and if the messageQueue contains more messages they'll be lost. Another naive approach would be to use a callback-like mechanism, which requires an extra object + I still need to synchronize the caller with the Callable in the background thread. Something like wait & notify although I have K threads running in the background.

What would be the sophisticated way to handle this situation of returning results of operations from within a message-loop in a different thread, without terminating the thread itself?

@Edit:
I'll give a description of the whole process so that it clarifies what is happening here.

1. A client sends a message (xml string) to the application through tcp sockets.
2. The application authenticates the client, and if the client has no associated handler it'll create one.
3. The app will push the message to the queue of the handler.
4. The handler runs in a separate thread waiting for incoming messages from clients they're associated with, they MUST NOT handle messages for other clients.
5. When the handler picks up a message it'll transform it into a SOAP message and will forward it to another system through TCP socket.
6. When the handler recieves the response it needs to delegate it back to the caller without terminating its message-loop.

So the caller is something like a Dispatcher dispatching messages to the threads that are running the handlers associated with the sender of the message. It also collects the response from the handlers and sends them back to the correct clients.

Each handler, currently has their own message queue where only those messages are pushed which the particular handle has to process. When a handler starts up, it'll open a TCP socket to the target system where they'll forward the incoming messages after transformations were applied. When the handler reaches the maximal allowed idle time (The socket were opened without sending a request) the socket will be closed and the message-loop stopped. At this point the handler will finish its execution. the purpose of this, is to have a socket for each individual clients through which they can send multiple requests without the need for the target system to do another authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few options/questions come to mind:

1. Is there a problem to terminate the thread, check the returned result and then re-submit this task to the same thread pool? You will get a result, analyze it, and then resubmit to the pool and continue the work
2. As this thread runs, it can submit the statuses to a different ("external") queue which is analyzed outside this thread. An independent thread always run and check this queue

That's as far as I could think on how to...

Comment: Unfortunately thread termination is out of scope but I left it out on purpose. The process operation means forwarding the message and read its response. If I was to terminate the thread, the socket would either go down or dangle in the system we forward the messages to. I'll update my original post to reflect it.
Point 2 seems a good alternative I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I'm sticking with your second option. I implemented that solution and it seems rather straight and flexible in term of my needs. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

### It depends on...

If you want to return simple type you can use a thead safe result queue (global or by caller).
Propably thread pool will be more suitable in your case.

I belive that the most universal way is callback mechanism.

Comment: If you want to take a look at something like this, the implementation of SwingWorker (while not perfect), is a great place to start. `javax.swing.SwingWorker` implements almost exactly the type of behavior you explained.

Comment: The problem with the callback mechanism is that, when I call a callback method within the thread, that'll be running inside the thread and not the caller. What I want is to signal from the thread to the caller to execute a function without the caller to stop what it's actually doing.

I'll take a look at SwingWorker in the meantime.

Comment: In this case (if you realy want to prepare result in caller thread) I'd use result queue in caller thread and some times check it.

Comment: Or use EventBus pattern with async call (if you want prepare result in another thread)